# Iam getting this error and i dont know how to fix it: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'warpPerspective'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'warpPerspective'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

````
import numpy as np

img = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    # Step 1: Define 4 corner points , use any photo editor like paint to get pixel location of the points
    pts1 = np.float32([[85,30],[150,30],[86,125],[150,125]])

    # Step 2: Define location of the points
    width, height = 250, 350 # getting required size by taking care of height & width ratio of card
    pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[width,0],[0,height],[width,height]])

    # Step 3: Make matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

    # Get Output image based on the above matrix
    imgOutput = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (width, height))

    cv2.imshow("Image",img)
    cv2.imshow("Output", imgOutput)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

img.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Comment: You are passing the video capture object to the function. You are supposed to get the frame input from the video and feed it as input

Comment: Within the `while` loop enter `ret, frame = img.read()`. Now pass `frame` as input to the warp function

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pay attention @Jeru Luke. You're missing one extra **cv2.cvtColor**. I changed in line #24 with **gray** instead of **img**.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while img.isOpened():
    ret, frame = img.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Step 1: Define 4 corner points , use any photo editor like paint to get pixel location of the points
    pts1 = np.float32([[85,30],[150,30],[86,125],[150,125]])

    # Step 2: Define location of the points
    width, height = 250, 250 # getting required size by taking care of height & width ratio of card
    pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[width,0],[0,height],[width,height]])

    # Step 3: Make matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

    # Get Output image based on the above matrix
    
    imgOutput = cv2.warpPerspective(gray, matrix, (width, height))

    cv2.imshow("Image", gray)
    cv2.imshow("Output", imgOutput)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

img.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm using Raspberry pi4/8gb, linux 4.5.5, Bullseye v11.